# Given the subspaces $S=\{(1,2,1),(0,2,0)\}$ and $P=\{(x,y,z): x+y=y-kz=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the subspaces $S=\{(1,2,1),(0,2,0)\}$ and $P=\{(x,y,z): x+y=y-kz=0\}$, try to find $k$ such that: $S+P=\mathbb R^3$ and $S∩P={(0,0,0)}$.

Sorry, I forgot to put what I did try first. Here I go:

First, I became aware that if $S+P$ is equal to $P$, then there the elements on the basis of S plus the elements on the basis of $P$ correspond to the basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

But we know that $\mathbb R^3$ has a canonical basis, that is: {$(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$}, and so now we can arrange $P$ so it can create this set.

This is my main idea, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Check your description of your plane $P$ - is that correct? It looks unconventional. Anyway, hint: Find something in $P$ not in the span of $S$ to force a direct sum.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think $S$ is supposed to be a plane, not $P$. One of them has to be a line in order to sum directly with a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basis for $S$ (presuming $S$ is the span of the two vector set, and thus a subspace). Note that the vectors are linearly independent, as they are not scalar multiples of each other.

Now you need a basis for $P$. The equations $x + y = 0$ and $y - kz = 0$ simplify to $y = kz$ and $x = -y = -kz$. So, for $(x, y, z) \in P$,
$$(x, y, z) = (-kz, kz, z) = z(-k, k, 1).$$
Thus, every element of $P$ is a scalar multiple of $(-k, k, 1)$. You can also check that $(-k, k, 1)$ (and hence all of its multiples) belongs to $P$, so $\{(-k, k, 1)\}$ is a basis.

Now you can apply the result, and I'll leave the rest to you: for which values of $k$ is $\{(1, 2, 1), (0, 2, 0), (-k, k, 1)\}$ a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Comment: whoa, know i see it, its two! thanks so much. everything its so clear now.

Comment: Well, it's not about finding one value of $k$ so that the above is a basis, it's about finding all such $k$. In fact, there is exactly one value of $k$ where this set is **not** a basis! See if you can find this $k$.

Answer (score 2):

The subspace $S$ *generated by* the *two* linearly independent vectors $(1,2,1)$ and $(0,2,0)$ is a plane and the subspace $Y$ *of $\mathbb R^3$* defined by the *two* linearly independent equations $x+y=0$ and $y - kz = 0$, is of dimension $3-2=1$.

Since the sum of their dimensions equals the dimension of $\mathbb R^3$, your two conditions (on the sum and intersection) are equivalent. The easier to handle is the second one.

A vector of $S$, $$a(1,2,1)+b(0,2,0)=(a,2a+2b,a),$$ also belongs to $Y$ if and only if $3a+2b=0$ and $(2-k)a+2b = 0$, i.e. $b=-3a/2$ and $(-1-k)a=0$. Hence the condition for $S∩P$ to be $\{(0,0,0)\}$ is $-1-k\ne0$ i.e. $k\ne-1.$